# Select query fails in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Please i am having this issue with my first **sqlachemy** app. I am trying to query the db which is posgres and return a row where it matches . Below is my code.

**app.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models.models import Base,User,Product,ProductItem,DATABASE, initialize

engine = DATABASE
Base.metadata.bind = (engine)

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

....


@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = RegisterForm.LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    return authenticate(form = form)

def authenticate(form):
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == 'xxxx@yahoo.com')
            if session.query(exists().where(User.email == form.email.data)).scalar() :
                return user.name
        except :# models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your email or password does not match !", "error")
            return 'error'
```

my modules is in a seperate folder modules

**modules/modules.py**

```
#declarations

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:0102443167@localhost:5432/postgres',echo=True)
Base.metadata.bind = (engine)

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

DATABASE = engine

class User(UserMixin , Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(CHAR(3), nullable = False)
    fname = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
    lname = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
    username = Column(String(100), nullable = False, unique = True)
    email = Column (String(50), nullable =False, unique = True)
    password = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
    address = Column(String(250), nullable = False)
    state = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
    is_Admin = Column(Boolean ,default = False)
    is_Logged = Column(Boolean, default = False)
    is_Active = Column (Boolean , default = False)
    is_Block = Column(Boolean, default = False)
    joined_On = Column(ArrowType)

    ......
```

My problem is with the `app.py` authenticate method. The code

```
user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == form.email.data)
```

Raise an error. When i check `form.email.data` return correct string. However when i tried

```
 if session.query(exists().where(User.email == form.email.data)).scalar() :
         return 'Ok'
```

works as expected. It works perfect and thus make me realize the issue might be with my query . I then tried

```
if session.query(exists().where(User.email == form.email.data)).scalar() :
       return user.lname
```

and it raise error saying user does not have property name which should have. I am confuse. Please how do i query record from my tables ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see any `user` property in your `User` class. You have only `fname`, `lname` and `username`.

Comment: @doru its my first attempt following a tut vid. My User class there mapped to my database. Also i import the Base, and the User class to my app.py. Please, can you give example of the user property you were expecting ? Perhaps i would learn from it . My confusion arises when my second query works . Had both of them fails ,  i may think there is problem with the module. Please help.

Comment: Try: `if session.query(exists().where(User.email == form.email.data)).scalar() :
       return user.username` and not `return user.name`

Comment: OOOPs.. Sorry . just realized i dont have a property name . Ayyo. Thank you sir. Have spent needless hours trying ot figure out this.

Comment: @duro there something is wrong with my `user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == form.email.data)` query still. When i changed to `user = session.query(User).first()` it returns data. However the later raise an error . I am not sure any more.

Comment: You have to get the first object which matches the query  so you have to add `.first()` at the end of the query: `user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == form.email.data).first()`.

Comment: @doru thanks . Thats exactly what i am looking for. The docs here does not specified that though http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html . thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the first object which matches the query so you have to add `.first()` at the end of the query:

```
user = session.query(User).filter(User.email == form.email.data).first()
```

See [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html) more info.